# Update fails because of validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, attributes, sql-update

if I try to update an attribute from my Student model it fails because of validations.

```
  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    if params['student']
      if params['student']['freedays']
        weekday_nbs = params['student']['freedays']&.first&.split(',')
        params['student']['freedays'] = weekday_nbs.inject([]){|sum, last| sum << Student::FREE_DAYS[last.to_i]}
      end
      if params['student']['vehicles']
        params['student']['vehicles'] = params['student']['vehicles']&.split(',')
      end
      if params['student']['driving_licenses']
        params['student']['driving_licenses'] = params['student']['driving_licenses']&.split(',')
      end
    end
    @student.update(student_params)
    redirect_to student_path(@student)
  end
```

This is the error I get when I try to update the attribute (:beschikbaar):

```
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: First name can't be blank, Last name can't be blank, Age can't be blank, Photo can't be blank, Studie can't be blank, Description can't be blank, Phone number can't be blank from /home/yves/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ac‌​tiverecord-5.0.1/lib‌​/active_record/valid‌​ations.rb:78:in`
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: "Anyone an idea how to fix this?" - umm, how about providing the required fields or removing the validations?

Comment: Please, post your Student model and your log!

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method *will invoke the validations* and will **not save** if the object is failed the validations. As you are trying to *update a particular attribute*, I suggest you to use [*`update_attribute`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) or [*`update_column`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) instead.

Just change

```
@student.update(student_params)
```

to

```
@student.update_attribute(beschikbaar: params[:beschikbaar])
```

**OR**

```
@student.update_column(beschikbaar: params[:beschikbaar])
```

Comment: Should I do this for all the attributes separately?

Comment: @crievino It depends on how many attributes you want to update at a time. If you want to update more than on attribute, then use [*update_columns*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns)